Is it possible to inject an AngularJS Service to an Angular 17+ component using inject()?
I'm working on upgrading AngularJS -> Angular 17. I currently have a hybrid application running side-by-side.
Currently, I inject AngularJS services that have not yet been upgraded by providing them to my app.module like so:
{
    deps: ["$injector"],
    provide: "Ng1Service",
    useFactory: (i) => i.get("Ng1Service")
},

...then, I use them in components like:
constructor(@Inject("Ng1Service") private ng1Service) {}

The weird part is when I'm trying to write my components with modern injection for both upgraded and legacy services.
export class MyClass {
    private modernService = inject(ModernService);

    constructor(@Inject("Ng1Service") private ng1Service) {}
}

I've tried both UpgradeModule and $injector with no luck:
export class MyClass {
    private ng1Service = inject("$injector").get("Ng1Service");
    private ng1Service2 = inject(UpgradeModule).$injector.get("Ng1Service");
}

I've tried both UpgradeModule and $injector with no luck:
export class MyClass {
    private ng1Service = inject("$injector").get("Ng1Service");
    private ng1Service2 = inject(UpgradeModule).$injector.get("Ng1Service");
}


Is the application you are migrating so big that you cannot convert all the legacy modules to angular 18? If it really is huge you could probably map certain paths to the legacy app... it seems to me to be akin to P****ng in your pants to call parts of the legacy application if it is not very big. The complexity of a migrated application ought to be smaller. if your authorization architecture is unchanged, you ought not have issues having some legacy parts called from your new interface

@JoSSte unfortunately, it's quite large. It's an enterprise application that was developed in AngularJS for 8 years. The hybrid side-by-side is working fine, and using @Inject() isn't terrible. In some ways it makes it easy to find what services we haven't migrated yet. TLDR; we already spent two years in a separate repo doing essentially a rewrite which got canned because new features were being requested faster than we could rewrite existing.

I understand. I have had a similar experence. Luckily I could cherry-pick some of the features so that I could slowly migrate it.
